# Instantiate an object without having it appear on startup

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to instantiate a sphere every time I press a button, in order to instantiate it must be cloned from an object I already created example: 'sphere1, so it will instantiate sphere1(clone)

I do not want sphere1 though to appear when I start the game. How can hide sphere 1?

Comment: If you are just creating a sphere you can use `GameObject.CreatePrimitive`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this 2 ways:

1). You can create a prefab of the object that you want to instantiate. This can be done by dragging the object in the scene into your assets folder, it will make an item that has a blue square for an icon and the objects name. This new item can be put in your script just like that of the gameobject sphere1 in the scene, but it will not be loaded in your scene unless you instantiate one.

2). You can also use your current method, however the sphere1 that is currently in your game scene you need to turn it to inactive. (The top checkbox by the name of the object in the inspector)
Now in your code, you need to use:

```
//Creates the object in the scene, ',,,,' is other parameters.
GameObject obj  = Instantiate(Sphere1Prefab,,,,);
//Changes the newly created object to active in the scene.
obj.SetActive(true);
```

Either of these should give you the desired effect.